# Loading data into dataTable with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I have this code to load the data table

```
  $(".dataTable").dataTable({"bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "datatable"});
```

This is the datatable file

```
return '{
  "aaData": [
    [
      "row 1 col 1 data",
      "row 1 col 2 data",
      "row 1 col 3 data",
      "row 1 col 4 data"

    ],
    [
      "row 2 col 1 data",
      "row 2 col 2 data",
      "row 2 col 3 data",
      "row 2 col 4 data"
    ],
    [
      "row 3 col 1 data",
      "row 3 col 2 data",
      "row 3 col 3 data",
      "row 3 col 4 data"
    ],
    [
      "row 4 col 1 data",
      "row 4 col 2 data",
      "row 4 col 3 data",
      "row 4 col 4 data"
    ]
  ]
}';
```

It keeps saying that the format of JSON is wrong.

Can you help me understanding what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What language are you using for sending the data?

Comment: I'm loading a dataTable jquery element with an ajax file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `"sEcho": 1,`  in the json which is needed for the AJAX load so try adding

```
"sEcho": 1,
```

before the

```
"aaData"
```

And change `return` to `echo` in case you are using `PHP` as the scripting language.

UPDATE here how the JSON should look like

```
echo '{
  "sEcho": 1, 
  "aaData": [
    [
      "row 1 col 1 data",
      "row 1 col 2 data",
      "row 1 col 3 data",
      "row 1 col 4 data"

    ],
    [
      "row 2 col 1 data",
      "row 2 col 2 data",
      "row 2 col 3 data",
      "row 2 col 4 data"
    ],
    [
      "row 3 col 1 data",
      "row 3 col 2 data",
      "row 3 col 3 data",
      "row 3 col 4 data"
    ],
    [
      "row 4 col 1 data",
      "row 4 col 2 data",
      "row 4 col 3 data",
      "row 4 col 4 data"
    ]
  ]
}';
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding where do you want me to put the "sEcho":1,

Anyway, I change the return to echo and tried to put the "sEcho":1, in several places but with no  sucess it just keeps saying that the format is wrong

Comment: I have updated the answer, check here how ajax loaded json works for datatable http://demo.sqcrm.com/  `u:admin` `p:abhik123` go to contact,leads etc and you can see how the json is generated using brwser development tool and also check the source code http://sqcrm.com/download.php